# how to post form slider rating value in the database in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, forms, post, slider

i have tried all the possible solutions to get the value but here i got the error every time.

this is my blade code

```
<form action="{{ route('post_review') }}" class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="content_id" value="{{ $content_dots->id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
<textarea class="form__textarea" name="review" placeholder="Review" required></textarea>
<div class="form__slider">
<div class="form__slider-rating" id="slider__rating"></div>
<div class="form__slider-value" id="form__slider-value">
<input type="hidden" id="form__slider-value" name="start_rating" value="5">
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="form__btn" name="submit" id="submit">Send Review</button>
</form>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form__slider-value").slider({
                min: 1,
                max: 10,
                value: 1,
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#start_rating").val(ui.value);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my review model

```
class Review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['review','start_rating','content_id','user_id','status'];

    public function getRules()
    {
        return [
            'review' => 'required|string',
            'start_rating' =>  'required|numeric',
            'status' => 'required|in:active,inactive',
        ];
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','id','user_id');
    }

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Content','id','content_id',);
    }

}
```

this is my content model

```
class Content extends Model
{
    public function review()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Review','id');
    }
}
```

this is my controller

```
class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    protected $review = null;
    protected $content = null;

    public function __construct(Review $review, Content $content)
    {
        $this->review = $review;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function postReview(Request $request)
    {
        $review = new Review();
        $review->review= $request->review;
        $review->start_rating = $request->input('start_rating');
        $review->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $review->content_id = $request->content_id;
        $review->status = $request->input('status','inactive');
        $review->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Your review has been submitted Successfully,');
    }
}
```

this is the error

[error i get when i submit the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vgAd.png)

i search for the possible output that i need but i cannot get the value.
i need that start_rating value to be posted in the database as shown in the red marked in the below picture.
[need the red marked value in the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA6y3.png)

Comment: what does `$request->dd()` give?

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "JJ1BjHI5vwdhIFrbZlupZ8PfWCdGQ5c3tqr2ishh"
  "content_id" => "2"
  "user_id" => "2"
  "review" => "okknk"
  "submit" => null
]

Comment: you should look into whatever you are using for the slider since you are passing no rating information into the request

Comment: i tried but it's not working. i repost the question also.

Comment: I think here: `slide: function(event, ui) { $("#start_rating").val(ui.value); }`

You are referencing the wrong element, since you don't have the element with aforementioned id. However, you have an input with the name that you used above.  Also, you have two elements with duplicate id-s : "form__slider-value". Either change the input id or div id, to avoid confusion.